# How to create COM-port in python on windows

Tags: python, windows, serial-port

I'm trying to create a serial port in python. I'm going to use it to communicate with another program that is communicating via a serial port. the PySerial package seems fine but I can't get it working. I've looked eveywhere and every implementation is for linux. **Can anyone help me create a COM port on windows and read/write to it?**

Comment: There's a Windows backend for [PySerial](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to create a serial port in Python, because you need a special driver for this task. You can only call 3rd party utility (with the drivers) that will do it for you.

I would recommend to try the following utilities:

Com0Com: http://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/

Virtual Null Modem: http://www.virtual-null-modem.com/

Comment: problem is:
Com0Com doesn't work( I get spamed with error codes)
and Virtual Null Modem is a paid solution with a trial(I need a permanent solution)

any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but Com0Com is the best free solution.